# Laravel 4: Unique Validation with Extra Condition While Updating Record

Tags: validation, laravel-4, unique, conditional-statements

I am soft deleting events in the database and while updating any event i need to check if user replace the value of "sysname" field with some existing (non deleted and active) event's sysname then i need to prevent it. Therefore, i just want to know that while applying unique validation for the relevant field, how would i assign a condition to check for `is_deleted = 0` and `status=1`

Here is my code of Event model:

```
public static function editrules($id=0, $merge=[]) {
    return array_merge(
        [
            'sysname' => 'required|unique:tblEvent,sysname,'.$id.',event_id',
        ], 
        $merge);
}
```

The above code simply prevent to update existing event "sysname" for the current event. But
i need to know that what code i need to add in above sample code to check existing non deleted (`is_deleted = 0`) and active event (`status=1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"unique:tblEvent,sysname,{$id},event_id,deleted_at,NULL,status,1"`

Comment: My field name was is_deleted :) So it worked like unique:tblEvent,sysname,{$id},event_id,is_deleted,0,status,1